# Limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \delta_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Here is a solution to a limit of a sequence, but i feel like the squeeze theorem is really needed to get the right answer, but i cant see how excactly it should be used.Thank you for any comment $!$.
\begin{align}
\delta_{n} & =
\frac{1}{2n}\,\sqrt[n]{\,{1^{n} + 2^{n} + \cdots +
\left(2n\right)^{n}}\,}\,
\\[2mm] & =
\,\sqrt[n]{\,{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n} +
\left(\frac{2}{2n}\right)^{n} + \cdots +
\left(\frac{2n}{2n}\right)^{n}}\,}\,\,\,\to 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using $k\leq 2n$ we have

$$\frac{1}{2n}\sqrt[n]{(2n)^n}\leq\frac{1}{2n}\sqrt[n]{1^n+\dots+(2n)^n}\leq\frac{1}{2n}\sqrt[n]{(2n)^n+\dots +(2n)^n}$$

from where we get
$$ 1\leq S_n\leq\sqrt[n]{2n}.$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2n}=1$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=1.$$

Comment: This makes perfect sense actually.Big thanks!